# Unable to open mysql from MAMP

Tags: command-line-interface, mamp, relative-path

I am unable to run MySQL through command line on windows 10. I have MAMP PRO 4.0.1 installed. I tried running "/Applications/MAMP/bin/MySQL -u root -p " from the command line, but I get an error stating "The system cannot find the path specified". I have added the path of MAMP to the environment variable, still, I am unable to run MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add PATH environment variable like "C:\MAMP\bin\" and then open new command prompt after that try below command

```
  mysql -uroot -p
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had to go to the phpini file in the MAMP and then change "display_words" to on. I also went to command line and entered the path of my mysql.exe file and entered the user and the password.